# PHP + MySQL is complicated

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using XMAPP and MySQL is running as it should. In phpMyAdmin, I don't really get the point so I tried creating one in PHP. With this code it tells me the database benutzer. benutzer doesn't exists although I created one in phpMyAdmin and in this code:

```
       <?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","") or die ("Alles scheisse!");
    $db = mysql_select_db("benutzer") or die ("Keine benutzer!");
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE 'benutzer'
    id VARCHAR(100),
    name VARCHAR(100),
    mail VARCHAR(100),
    points INT(1000)
    )";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO benutzer(`id` , `name` , `mail` , `points`)VALUES(NULL , 'Liam', 'liam@mail.com', '100');";
$db_erg = mysql_query($sql)
   or die("Anfrage fehlgeschlagen: " . mysql_error());
        ?>
```

Comment: your question title says nothing about your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Have you also created a table "benutzer" inside db "benutzer"? Your code does not execute your first SQL statement "CREATE TABLE.." so there will be no table "benutzer"  if you don't have one created in phpmyadmin.

Comment: This. You needlessly assign the `CREATE TABLE...` statement to the variable `$sql` and then don't execute the query.

Comment: Yeah, seems like he meant for the second `$sql = ...` line to be an augmented concatenation assignment `$sql .= ...`.

Comment: Well, either that or just running them both as separate queries.  The first would require adding a `; ` to the end of the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Did you created the database under the root user? Because you are connecting to the root in your code.